# Calculate Number of Consecutive Characters in a String using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string with multiple sequences of consecutive characters like:

```
aaabbcccdddd
```

I want to represent this as: `a3b2c3d4`

As of now, I have come up with this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

$str = "aaabbcccdddd";
$str =~ s/(.)\1+/$1/g;

print $str."\n";
```

Output:

```
abcd
```

It stores the consecutive characters in the capture buffer and returns only one. However, I want a way to count the number of consecutive characters in the capture buffer and then display only one character followed by that count so that it displays the output as `a3b2c3d4` instead of `abcd`.

What modification is required to the above regex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to require the 'execute' option on the substitute command so the replacement text is treated as a fragment of Perl code:

```
 $str =~ s/((.)\2+)/$2 . length($1)/ge;
```

#### Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $original = "aaabbcccdddd";
my $alternative = "aaabbcccddddeffghhhhhhhhhhhh";

sub proc1
{
    my($str) = @_;
    $str =~ s/(.)\1+/$1/g;
    print "$str\n";
}

proc1 $original;
proc1 $alternative;

sub proc2
{
    my($str) = @_;
    $str =~ s/((.)\2+)/$2 . length($1)/ge;
    print "$str\n";
}

proc2 $original;
proc2 $alternative;
```

#### Output

```
abcd
abcdefgh
a3b2c3d4
a3b2c3d4ef2gh12
```

---

> Could you please break down the regular expression to explain how it works?

*I'm assuming it is the match part that is problematic and not the replacement part.*

The original regex is:

```
(.)\1+
```

This captures a single character `(.)` that is followed by the same character repeated one or more times.

The revised regex is 'the same', but also captures the whole pattern:

```
((.)\2+)
```

The first open parenthesis starts the overall capture; the second open parenthesis starts the capture of a single character.  But, it is now the second capture, so the `\1` in the original needs to become `\2` in the revision.

Because the search captures the whole string of repeated characters, the replacement can determine the length of the pattern easily.

Answer (score 1):

The following works if you can live with the slow-down caused by `$&`:

```
$str =~ s/(.)\1*/$1. length $&/ge;
```

Changing the `*` to `+` in the above expression leaves non-consecutive characters untouched.

As JRFerguson reminds, Perl 5.10+ provides an equivalent `${^MATCH}` variable that does not affect regex performance:

```
$str =~ s/(.)\g{1}+/$1. length ${^MATCH}/pge;
```

For Perl 5.6+, the performance hit can still be avoided:

```
$str =~ s/(.)\g{1}+/ $1. ( $+[0] - $-[0] ) /ge;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will learn more about the regular expressions :)

Comment: Perl 5.10 introduced `${^MATCH}` to avoid the performance hit of `$&`.  See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: To limit the performance hit, add the '\p' modifier to the match.  Then, `${^PREMATCH"` `${^MATCH}` and `${^POSTMATCH}` are captured only for the the match in question, and not every one.

Comment: @JRFerguson : I don't see it making any difference to the end result in this case.

Comment: @Zaid : I only thought a bit of clarification of how to avoid the performance penalty might be in order.  Personally, I liked your answer regardless.

Comment: There seems to be a serial drive-by non-commenting down-voter; someone doesn't like the solution you and I have given, but is not prepared to take the time to provide their own better solution or comment on why down-votes are warranted.  It's a nuisance; it happens; there isn't much either of us can do about it except commiserate with each other.

Comment: @JRFerguson : According to [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), the `/p` guarantees that `${^PREMATCH}`, `${^MATCH}` and `${^POSTMATCH}` will be defined in the event of a successful match. It is a good reason to use it; is that what you meant by your earlier comment?

Comment: @Zaid : My understanding is that by using `\p` you limit the penalty to the match operation instead of taking it everywhere. That is, if you use `-p` the `${^PREMATCH}`, `${^MATCH}` and `${^POSTMATCH}` are set only for that match; not everyone --- a performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
let data = "ababaaaabbbababb";

data.replace(/((.)\2+)/g, (match, p1, p2) =>  {
  data = data.replace(new RegExp(p1, 'g'), p2 + p1.length);
});

console.log(data);
```